# How to prevent the prerequisite of a target from expanding when the target is not used?

Tags: makefile

In a Makefile with multiple targets, how can one prevent the prerequisites of targets that are not being used from expanding? See the following example:

```
thisexpands = $(warning Expanded!)

.PHONY: target1
target1: $(thisexpands)
    @echo Target 1

.PHONY: target2
target2:
    @echo Target 2
```

Calling `target2` forces `thisexpands` to expand, even though it is lazily evaluated and it and `target1` are never used.

In my real world case expanding `thisexpands` when calling `target1` is an issue, because it is a shell command that prints errors when called out of context of target1 and it's parent targets(not shown here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to cancel the expansion completely. However, you can use the conditional assignment based on the value of `$(MAKECMDGOALS)`:

```
thisexpands = $(if $(filter target1,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),$(warning Expanded!))

.PHONY: target1
target1: $(thisexpands)
    @echo Target 1

.PHONY: target2
target2:
    @echo Target 2
```

Note that it works if `target1` is only built explicitly (`make target1`) and not by default, or as a part of building another target.

Answer (score 2):

Makefiles are fully parsed before the first rule is run.  As part of parsing, all the targets and prerequisites must be expanded.  You can find details of when expansion happens for different parts of a makefile in [How make Reads a Makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html) in the GNU make manual.

One way is to use recursion:

```
thisexpands = $(warning Expanded!)

target1: ; $(MAKE) target1-recurse T1_DEPS='$(value thisexpands)'

T1_DEPS =
target1-recurse: $(T1_DEPS)
        @echo Target 1
```

**This doesn't work:**

You can probably defer expansion by using [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html), something like this:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
target1: $$(thisexpands)
```

Be very careful that you escape the prerequisite list appropriately.

Comment: Unfortunately, it only defers the expansion, not really cancels it.

Comment: You're right.  I wonder why it works like that.  It seems like it would be more efficient to wait until the target is needed before expansion.  However, that would mean modifying the DAG during the tree walk, which is definitely not a trivial change, so that's probably why.

Comment: `to wait until the target is needed before expansion` But what if make would need "to try" some intermediate target which turns to be "unneeded" at the end? If its prerequisites would get expanded due to the internals of the algorithm, while others not, that would be counterintuitive to say the least.

Comment: Also such expansion would probably be in the "graph-walk" order, not in the "file" order. And this could result in some evil side-effects.

Comment: I'm not sure what you  mean by "file order"; maybe "makefile order"?  But this is irrelevant in my example because I've enabled secondary expansion, so the expansion already happens at the end after the makefile has been read in, in some random order.

Comment: I'm also not sure what you mean by "try some intermediate target"; if make needs to find the child nodes of a node in the graph, and to do that it needs to expand the prerequisites of this node, then it will.  If it never reaches that node, then it won't.  Since make walks the graph once in a known order and there can be no cycles, I don't see how that order could be changed by deferring the expansion until the node is visited during the walk.

Comment: You're right. For some reason I thought that the second expansion is done in the makefile order, just like the first one. But It's not. Also make already ignores the second expansion of unused pattern rules, as one may expect.